# Android: NoClassDefFound error

Tags: android

My setup is as follows:

I have an android project A, and a java project B. Project A uses some files from Project B.

My development environment is eclipse, and I have included Project B in the build path,
as well as marked it for 'Order and export'.

The project builds fine, but at runtime I get a

java.lang.NoClassDefFound error, when I am trying to reference a class from Project B.

How can I resolve this?

I am using eclipse Juno, and ADT 20.0.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you imported your project using Eclipse in-built importing or the one found on Android project settings? Meaning is project B a library project?

Comment: No, porject B is not a library project. It is a simple java project.

Comment: The same mechanism used to work for Eclipse ganymede with an earlier version of ADT, but after updating my eclipse and ADT, it has broken.

Answer (score 0):

As you talk about having updated your Eclipse and your ADT, maybe you also changed your environment to Java 7?
If that is the case, the answer would be:
Switch back to Java 1.6.x, as Java 7 is not (yet?) supported by Android.

You need to change the "**compiler compliance level**" under:

*Window - Preferences -- Java - Compiler - Compiler compliance level*

Hope that works, at least it did for me:
[NoClassDefFoundError when referencing from an Android-Project to a standard Java-Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963835/noclassdeffounderror-when-referencing-from-an-android-project-to-a-standard-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to export the java classes you need in a jar, and include that jar in your Android project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to reference another class withing the same project itself.In my case, the problem was solved when I rechecked the android dependencies. I added two jar files for a single required file. There was a need of android-support-v4.jar file in my project. I added the library twice by mistake. The error was resolved when I deleted one of them.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happening when using the AIDE development environment. It has happened a couple of times over the past year.

When the Java diamond operator is used to specify a function's generic type the program will compile, but the Dalvic engine crashes with the NoClassDefFound exception.

To fix this I had to explicitly define the generic type.

By the way, this crash can happen in a completely different place to where the problem actually is. For example, we have classes A and B. The bad code is at A.myMethod(). The crash will happen when class B attempts to access any part of class A, even something unrelated such as A.myOther() method.

This is because of how Java/Dalvic loads classes at runtime only when first accessed.